# Why does this applescript that tasks to iTunes sometimes fail with -1712

Tags: applescript, itunes

I have some applescript for creating a list of the fiels under iTunes control and writing it to a file, this is the complete script:

```
tell application "iTunes"

    if (count of every file track of library playlist 1) is equal to 0 then
        set thePath to (POSIX file "/tmp/songkong_itunes_model.txt")
        set fileref to open for access (thePath) with write permission
        set eof fileref to 0
        return
    end if

    tell every file track of library playlist 1
        script performancekludge
            property tracknames : its name
            property locs : its location
            property persistids : its persistent ID
        end script
    end tell
end tell

set thePath to (POSIX file "/tmp/songkong_itunes_model.txt")
set fileref to open for access (thePath) with write permission
set eof fileref to 0

tell performancekludge
    repeat with i from 1 to length of its tracknames
        try
            set nextline to item i of its tracknames ¬
                & "::" & POSIX path of item i of its locs ¬
                & "::" & item i of its persistids
            write nextline & linefeed as «class utf8» to fileref
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

close access fileref
```

and sometimes it gives

```
create_itunes_model.scpt:428:436: execution error: iTunes got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)
```

for some users, but I dont know why

Does anybody know why, or how I could improve my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should `close access fileref` before your first return. Otherwise the text file could stay in an opened state.

The error looks like a timeout if the user's iTunes Library is too big and the script takes too much time to run. You should use a with timeout-block:

```
with timeout of 600 seconds
    -- your script here
end timeout
```

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: @SherTerKo Ok thanks I see the fileref issue - Ill fix that. I think you might have something about timing out if iTunes library too big, so what is the default timeout  if I don't set one, is it larger or less than 600 seconds, i,e does your change reduce or increase the default timeout. My script has to deal with large libraries so can I just increase the timeout or do I have to break the script processing into parts somehow ?

Comment: AFAIK the standard timeout is about 120 seconds. You should be able to set your timeout to any value you want. I remember scripts that worked with a timeout set to two or more hours!

Comment: 2 minutes is that all !, okay you really may be onto something here I'll get a customer to test this out and if it solves the problem mark your answer right ( and give you a bounty as well)